# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') - Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm getting this error randomly with discord.js v13.

[image: Error I'm getting]

For a bit of context, I'm running multiple bots on same script (so bot script loops through bot tokens and creates clients for all of them and listens for events from all of them).

I'm not encountering that error locally during dev but encountering it quite a bit on production server. If I had to guess, it's most likely related to multiple bots but beyond that I have no idea what's going on.

The error being thrown is an internal error occurring in `node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/ThreadMemberUpdate.js:12`:

```js
class ThreadMemberUpdateAction extends Action {
  handle(data) {
    const client = this. Client;
    // Discord sends the thread id as id in this object
    const thread = client.channels.cache.get(data.id);
    //           This right here   ^^^^^
    if (thread) {
      const member = thread.members.cache.get(data.user_id);
      if (!member) {
        const newMember = thread.members._add(data);
        return { newMember };
      }
      const old = member._update(data);
      /**
       * Emitted whenever the client user's thread member is updated.
       * @event Client#threadMemberUpdate
       * @param {ThreadMember} oldMember The member before the update
       * @param {ThreadMember} newMember The member after the update
       */
      client.emit(Events.THREAD_MEMBER_UPDATE, old, member);
    }
    return {};
  }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

#### Specs

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Node.JS Version: v10.19.0
Discord.JS Version: 13.15.1
```

Comment: Can you  do ```console.log(client)``` after declaring. There's prob no cache property on the members property of client.

Comment: What is your code?